# Stationarize a time series

Tags: python, time-series

I am trying to stationarize the time series data that I got from [this](https://datamarket.com/data/set/22z2/industrial-production-spain-monthly#!ds=22z2&display=line) link. I tried the following:

1) used diff 3 times

2) tried sqrt transformation on the data.

I still find trend and seasonal components when I decompose the differenced data.

I'm using Python and this is what I use for differencing

```
 diff1 = series.diff()
```

Answer (score 0):

Level shifts in the data require a different approach (see more from Balke [here](http://amstat.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/07350015.1993.10509934)). Try an AR2 with 1 outlier(0,1,0, etc,) at period 35, a level shift beginning at 47 (0,0,0,0,1,1,1,etc) and a seasonal pulse beginning at period 9(August is low 0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0 etc.) and forward.

There is seasonality in your data not handled by the typical approaches as it only occurs in some of the months.

Y(T) =  148.83                                spain
       +[X1(T)][(- 39.4158)]                            :SEASONAL PULSE 1978/  8     9   I~S00009spain
       +[X2(T)][(+ 17.5796)]                            :LEVEL SHIFT    1981/ 10    47   I~L00047spain
       +[X3(T)][(- 22.0482)]                            :PULSE          1980/ 10    35   I~P00035spain
      +     [(1-  .403B** 1-  .261B** 2)]**-1  [A(T)]   spain

[image: ACF - Residuals]

[image: PACF Residuals]

Comment: Thanks Tom, I'm going to take some time to understand your answer. Appreciate your effort

Comment: How did that go?